# How to jump to a row of a DataView based on partial match search criteria?

Tags: vb.net, dataset, dataview, c1flexgrid

Currently, my application uses the RowFilter property on an expression to search for a user-defined string within a DataView. Currently my code looks something like this:

```
Public Class MyClass
   Private custView As DataView
Private Sub form_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
   dsDataSet = <"DataAccessLayer call to SQL Stored Procedure">
   custView = New DataView(dsDataSet.Tables(0))
   custView.Sort = "Column Name"
   Me.C1FlexGrid1.DataSource = custView
End Sub
Private Sub txtSearch_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtSearch.TextChanged
    Dim searchText As String = txtSearch.Text
    Dim expression As String = "Column Name LIKE '" + searchText + "%'"

    custView.RowFilter = expression
    Me.C1FlexGrid1.DataSource = custView
End Sub
End Class
```

My goal is to modify the behavior of this such that instead of filtering out rows that do not meet the search results, it will keep all rows present but jump to the first instance of a partial match as the user types in the search box. If DataView.Find() supported wildcards I would be set, but unfortunately it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I've come up with is to use some iteration logic. However this is done on the object the DataView has been bound to and not the DataView itself. Although this code can be modified to do exactly that.

```
Private Sub txtSearch_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtSearch.TextChanged
        'Unselect all
        Me.C1FlexGrid1.Select(-1, -1, True)

        If txtSearch.Text <> "" And [column index] <> -1 Then
            'Typed text
            Dim s As String = txtSearch.Text.Trim.ToLower
            Dim column As Int32 = [column index] + 1

            'Recurse until match in first column is found
            For i As Integer = 0 To Me.C1FlexGrid1.Rows.Count - 1
                If C1FlexGrid1.GetData(i, column) <> Nothing Then
                    If C1FlexGrid1.GetData(i, column).ToString.ToLower.StartsWith(s) Then
                        Me.C1FlexGrid1.Select(i, column, True)
                        Exit Sub
                    End If
                Else

                    MsgBox("Error message", vbOKOnly, "NO MATCHES")

                    'Reset search criteria
                    Call ResetSearch()

                End If
            Next
            MsgBox("Error message", vbOKOnly, "NO MATCHES")
        End If
    End Sub
```